# how to count a key name of an array from jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys I have an array which is been `encoded` in `json` format.It looks like below :-

```
{"result":[{"pid":"24","uf":"hancy061","ot":"sanjit061","dn":"November 6,2015 at 02:18pm","view":"0","nu":"hancy061"},{"pid":"23","uf":"hari061","ot":"sanjit061","dn":"November 6,2015 at 01:09pm","view":"0","nu":"hari061"}]}
```

now in short my question is that can i count the total number of `view` from jquery/javascript?I want to count the `view` and store that number in a `var`.Please it might not be big deal to just count such thing.Is there any way to count that `view` from  jquery/javascript?Help needed guys.

Comment: you could `JSON_decode` it and iterate over it (`foreach decodedArray AS key => value)` and count the occurences of `key=='view'`

Comment: you can post in answer bro it will be good for me and you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` and [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
var data = JSON.stringify({
    "result": [{
        "pid": "24",
        "uf": "hancy061",
        "ot": "sanjit061",
        "dn": "November 6,2015 at 02:18pm",
        "view": "0",
        "nu": "hancy061"
    }, {
        "pid": "23",
        "uf": "hari061",
        "ot": "sanjit061",
        "dn": "November 6,2015 at 01:09pm",
        "view": "0",
        "nu": "hari061"
    }]
});

var count = (data.match(/view/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: @SOuřaan Gřg  I've added some description http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/y17oqky0/2/